# Single Unit Test in IntelliJ fails to find Spring .properties file

Tags: java, spring, junit

When running a single JUnit test in IntelliJ, using the `@SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` with a `@ContextConfiguration` that points to a test-context-spring.xml, I was getting the following Exception upon startup:

```
TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property ${...}
```

Answer (score 2):

After much struggle, and several unhelpful Stack Overflow answers (indicating that Spring had found more than one .properties file), I decided to run the same test through Eclipse.  Low and behold it worked.

So it's an IntelliJ issue.  To resolve:

`File > Project Structure > Modules > (Pick your Module) > Sources`

Under Sources, do two things:

1. highlight your Test Source folder (mine was /src/test) and click "Tests" at the top.
2. highlight the folder where your Spring application properties can be found (mine was /src/test/resources) and click "Test Resources" at the top.

Run your tests again.  It should find the properties file.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't import as a Maven/Gradle project; this should have happened automatically.